# Tab bar invisible in iOS

Tags: ios, swift3, storyboard, uitabbar

In a project I made a tableview that works well. Below this tableView I would like to add a tab bar. I tried everything and I do not know if the error is in my tableview or in my tab bar.

[image]

Result in Simulator :

[image]

I do not know if it is this tableview break that prevents tabbar display
[image]

Comment: Do you want a Tab Bar, or a Tool Bar.  A Tab Bar is used to navigate through out your app.  A tool bar is designed to focus on the current view and act on that, for example- close the view, save the data in the view.

Comment: I want a tab bar but no matter what appears on the bottom bar not even a one icon and the hide is disabled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your Document Outline, you've added a TabBarItem to you Controller, yet you haven't added a Tab Bar.  You might want to consider adding a TabBarViewController as it will take care of much of the work for you.

You want to select your TableViewController, Select Editor from XCode Menu, then Embed In, then select Tab Bar Controller.

Any other Views which should appear as tabs can be added by control dragging from the TabBarController.

Comment: thank you for your answer I remade with the assistant but still no tab bar that appears

Comment: can you remove the tab bar item you added to your Controller? In Document Outline, it's the star.

Comment: before I could now no I can no longer actually

Comment: Can you delete the bottom constraint on the tableview and reset to Bottom Layout Guide, not the View.

Comment: Last.  Drag a Tab Bar Item onto your TableViewController.

Comment: nothing, I may have disabled this option because in all my project I do not see the bottom

Answer (score 1):

Try this one.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

   self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true

}
```